# How to check for each item of JSON array of objects for a specific value?

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, object, foreach

Im using REACT JS. My JSON array of Objects has format below:

```js
{
        "records": {
            "Master Automotives": [
                {
                    "SparePartID": "43",
                    "Name": "Oil and Lubricants",
                    "err": ""
                },
                {
                    "SparePartID": "45",
                    "Name": "Lights",
                    "err": "Stock Error"
                }
            ],
            "Repair Solutions": [
                {
                    "SparePartID": "47",
                    "Name": "Steering Wheel",
                    "err": ""
                }
            ],
            
             "FiveStar Automotives": [
                {
                    "SparePartID": "51",
                    "Name": "Brakes",
                    "err": ""
                },
                {
                    "SparePartID": "53",
                    "Name": "Clutch",
                    "err": "Stock Error"
                },
                  {
                    "SparePartID": "55",
                    "Name": "LED",
                    "err": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Now in a method called **placeOrder**() I want to check if there is any item in above JSON which has column "**err**" value = "Stock Error" if any one or more items has the **err** value, I wanna set state of **check** to true.

But all items has err value equal to null i.e. **err=""** then it should setState of **check** to **false**.

I tried this code below but it doesn't work. Can u tell me what Im doing wrong:

```js
placeOrder()
{

const arr = {...this.state.myrecords};

Object.keys(arr).forEach(key => {
   if (arr[key].err === 'Stock Error')
    {
     this.setState({
              check: true
        })
       }
   })
   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this regex solution:

```js
const obj = {
        "records": {
            "Master Automotives": [
                {
                    "SparePartID": "43",
                    "Name": "Oil and Lubricants",
                    "err": ""
                },
                {
                    "SparePartID": "45",
                    "Name": "Lights",
                    "err": "Stock Error"
                }
            ],
            "Repair Solutions": [
                {
                    "SparePartID": "47",
                    "Name": "Steering Wheel",
                    "err": ""
                }
            ],
            
             "FiveStar Automotives": [
                {
                    "SparePartID": "51",
                    "Name": "Brakes",
                    "err": ""
                },
                {
                    "SparePartID": "53",
                    "Name": "Clutch",
                    "err": "Stock Error"
                },
                  {
                    "SparePartID": "55",
                    "Name": "LED",
                    "err": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    };

const objString = JSON.stringify(obj);
const regPattern = /\bStock Error\b/;
const result = objString.match(regPattern);
console.log(result); // This will log the first "stock error" in your object so you know if there is one
```

Usage:

If result.length > 0 // At least 1 stock error present
If result.length === 0 // No stock error present

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding correctly, you are one step behind, i.e. you are accessing `arr[key]`, this will only provide you the internal array.

That is

```
[
    {
        "SparePartID": "43",
        "Name": "Oil and Lubricants",
        "err": ""
    },
    {
        "SparePartID": "45",
        "Name": "Lights",
        "err": "Stock Error"
    }
]`
```

You need to check those array elements for `err`.

`arr[key][0].err === 'Stock Error'`

This will check for the first index. 
You can further implement a `map` function on an array for checking all elements.